# How do you add a table to a site?

Tags: customization

How do you add a simple table to a Wordpress page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a table to a WordPress page is really bit confusing as it may many cases. It would have been easy to answer if the question could be made specific to certain situations like a pricing table/ data table etc or a responsive one.

However, you can follow these steps to add a table inside your WordPress post.
**If you are using WordPress default editor:**

- Create a table in any word processor (like MS Word)
- Copy that table by `ctrl + c`
- Paste that inside your visual WordPress editor `ctrl + v`.

**If you want to add it by WordPress text editor.**
You can find some awesome free table templates by googling. You can refer to below link if you want to.
https://codepen.io/gillesdandrea/pen/aOzewP

- Refer this code and design your own table.
- Paste your code inside the WordPress text editor.

You can also do the same thing by a page template or creating a plugin.